# Redis Sentinel Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused on Ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, redis, redis-cluster, sentinel, redis-sentinel

I am trying to connect the master node to slave nodes.

I have created three instances one is master node and another two instance is slave nodes

when i am trying automatic failover in redis sentinel both of the slave node got this response
redis.log

```
Error condition on socket for SYNC: Connection refused
80231:S 08 Oct 2021 06:27:18.717 * Connecting to MASTER 12.205.144.275:6379
80231:S 08 Oct 2021 06:27:18.717 * MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the sentinel(26379) and Redis(6379) port open in firewall(Security Group).